# Debugging a Delphi DLL from a Visual Studio Test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to attach the Delphi Debugger to a Visual Studio test that is exercising the Delphi dll which I want to debug. Now I've done this before when the host is a visual studio application, but apparently the test project is an assembly so not sure what host I need to attach to. Anybody else tried this.

Comment: This is easy enough to work out. Run the test and see what process is hosting it. Use a tool like task manager or Process Explorer or Process Hacker.

Comment: Actually it's not that easy. It's not Devenv.exe and it seems to be a process called TE.Processhost.managed.exe. But this process only gets created on debugging the visual studio tests and attaching to it from the Delphi debugger doesn't seem to help. I know I have everything setup correctly (the correct Delphi dll etc etc), as I can debug the dll when the host is Excel VBA for example. In that case, it is easy, just attach to Excel.exe.

Comment: I would have expected there to be a standalone test runner that you could use. Which test framework are you using? NUnit?

Comment: It's just MSTest. That was my next avenue of attack...perhaps the two debuggers (Visual studio and Delphi) just can't live together.

Comment: I don't think you can have two debuggers active on one process

Comment: tried running the test in the standalone mstest.exe (i.e. running the Delphi dll with mstest as the host. Still can't debug the Delphi dll. It's a COM dll, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is the COM server in proc or out of proc in a surrogate process?

Comment: In process COM server

Comment: Surprising that it won't debug. It can sometimes be hard to get Delphi to attach to processes that debug a DLL.

Comment: I can attach to a Native process that uses the DLL, I can attach to Excel VBA using the DLL and I have even attached to ASP.NET using the DLL before. MSTest must be special.